# How to play online horse tournament when you lack knowledge in one of the games?

Tags: online, strategy

I really like play h.o.r.s.e and I am pretty good at it.
my problem is that I am a mediocre player at stud. In all the other games I am pretty good (I think I am above average in Holdem, Stud hi/low and Razz and highly above average in Omaha hi/low).

My question is How should I plan my game in order to avoid big hands in stud and how should I overcome loses due to passive game in this part.

Remark: I am practicing in stud all the time, but it seems that I just can't understand the logic of the game (I know the strategies and the good starting hands)

thanks,
Amigal

Comment: You're good at Stud Hi/Lo but not at Stud Hi ? Seriously ??

Comment: whats wrong with that? I am pretty good at split games. Its totally a different game. why do you comments with such disrespect?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't mean to be disrespectful. It just seems unlikely that you you're good at Stud Hi/Lo and not at Stud Hi. I see it as: Stud Hi/Lo = Stud Hi + Stud Lo, if that makes sense. So for you to know Stud Hi/Lo, you HAVE TO know Stud Hi. That was my point.

Comment: the game structure of stud and stud hi/low is the same, but the strategy/starting hands/hand value/etc. is totaly different. I can discuss a lot about the major differences between split games and regular games (from strategic point of view), but this is subject to another question.

Comment: It's certainly possible to do well at Stud Hi-Low and poorly at regular Stud. I'm not sure we can think of the Hi game as a completely separate component in Hi-Low, enough to say studying one automatically improves the other. (It helps to know the rules, though :).) Your question answers itself: either avoid putting in a lot of money against better Stud players, or get better at Stud (how to do this is too broad of a question).

Comment: I have to agree that S and E are completely different games--most people are better at high stud and clueless at high-low, though (I've seem stud players in high-low raise with hands like KKQ, for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious answer is to practice and study in the game that is your weakness. You've noted that you're already doing that, which is certainly a good step.

That said, you will always have some games that are more of a strength than others. My solution is, quite simply, to play extremely tight in the game(s) that you are weak in. By only playing strong starting hands, you will face fewer tough spots in your weak games. Then you can use the games that you are good at to "play poker" (i.e. exploit weaknesses in your opponents, make plays, etc) and amass chips.

The only place this falls apart is if you end up playing in your weak game while holding a short stack. There, your stack is going to do so much to dictate your play that you will have to take some chances when situations call for it. This, however, should be an area that you're reasonably well-equipped to handle, since you have a good background in related games. That is, because of your related knowledge of other stud games, you should be able to spot typical stud stealing spots, and have enough starting hand knowledge to know what's good enough when you have to make a desparate move.

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely cannot bring up your Stud High game, then simply play tight when that game comes around.  Play only the top 7 starting hands, and play them aggressively.  If you hand improves after a few more cards, you're probably good.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a better way to put it in my mind, so I'll just say it...

Either practice to improve your weaker games, or do your best to avoid them in the mixed games!

I think as @LocNguyen said in a comment, it's *perhaps* too broad a question.